# xlWorkBook.SaveAs with customizable name

Tags: c#, .net, excel

I need to convert an existing db database.db to an excel sheet with the name "StudentPass /currentdate and time/"

```
  DateTime dt = DateTime.Now;
        name =  dt.ToString();
        MessageBox.Show(name);
        string dbname=name;

        xlWorkBook.SaveAs(string.Format("StudentPass\\{0}.xls",name), Excel.XlFileFormat.xlWorkbookNormal, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, Excel.XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlExclusive, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue);
```

this is the code i am trying but it keep saying check if file exists.

```
        xlWorkBook.SaveAs("StudentPass.xlsx", Excel.XlFileFormat.xlWorkbookNormal, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, Excel.XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlExclusive, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue);
```

does the job but how do i add date and time to the name?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
xlWorkBook.SaveAs(string.Format("StudentPass {0:yyyy-MM-dd}.xls",dt), Excel.XlFileFormat.xlWorkbookNormal, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, Excel.XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlExclusive, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue);
```

**UPDATE :**

```
xlWorkBook.SaveAs(string.Format("StudentPass {0:yyyy-MM-dd_hh-mm-ss-tt}.xls",dt), Excel.XlFileFormat.xlWorkbookNormal, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, Excel.XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlExclusive, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue);
```

Comment: works for date but time is still missing. any solutions for that?